# Dropping Pandas Columns Inplace Triggers SettingWithoutCopy Warning

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to drop some superfluous columns from a pandas dataframe. Because I'm actually working with two such dataframes (both having the same superfluous columns). My little pipeline is as follows:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('path/x.csv') #another warning, possibly unrelated, see below
df2=pd.read_csv('path/y.csv')
df1=df1[df1['CODE']=='NV1']
df2=df2[df2['CODE']=='QUT1']
bad_cols=['Unnamed: 0','phrase']
df1.drop(bad_cols,axis=1,inplace=True) # triggers SettingWithoutCopy Warning
df2.drop(bad_cols,axis=1,inplace=True) # works fine, no warning
```

If I can verify that the drop worked (by calling `df1['phrase']` etc), is this warning save to ignore? I'm confused because it seems like SettingWithoutCopy should never get thrown if I set `inplace=True`.

Besides having columns that don't overlap 100% (around 25% of columns in common) and different numbers of rows, there is one material difference between `df1` and `df2` -- calling `df1=pd.read_csv('path/x.csv')` raises `sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,3341) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.` I'm not sure if this could be related to the `SettingWithoutCopy` discrepancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the step `df1=df1[df1['CODE']=='NV1']` and `df2=df2[df2['CODE']=='QUT1']` return views of the original `df1` and `df2`. The `SettingWithoutCopy` later warns when you try to modify one of those in place.

If you comment out the `df1.drop(bad_cols,axis=1,inplace=True)`, I expect the next line to raise the same Exception.

There are a number of possible solutions

- reverse the order of operations
- don't drop inplace but do `df1 = df1.drop(..)`
- select with loc: `df2=df2.loc[df2['CODE']=='QUT1',:]` should return a copy too

Answer (score 1):

you can do everything in one command:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('path/x.csv').drop(bad_cols,1).query("CODE=='NV1'")
```

if you have a full list columns that should remain, then do it this way:

```
cols = ['colA','colC','colZ',...]
df1 = pd.read_csv('path/x.csv', usecols=cols).query("CODE=='NV1'")
```

Comment: this is elegant and helpful, thank you. one thing to note (probably obvious to most) is that `CODE` cannot be in `bad_cols` - would need to drop such columns after reading

Comment: @MikePalmice, you can first `.query()` and then `.drop(...)` in that case. Just change the order of chained calls

Comment: for the line `.query("CODE=='NV1'")`, how would I alter it if NV1 is in a variable (eg, if preceded by `for code in poss_codes:`?

Comment: @MikePalmice, it would be `.query("CODE==@var_name")`

Comment: FYI, it happened that `.query().drop(,axis=1,inplace=True)` doesn't drop the columns. however, calling `.query()` and `.drop()` on successive lines works fine